# Using an iframe for sandboxing?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am developing a system that allows userwritten javascript in widgets. To keep things secure, I plan to sandbox these widgets in iframes. Of course, for the sandboxing to be effective the iframe must have a different domain than the parent document.

I would really love to be able to dynamically generate the iframe with code similar to this:

```
template = '<html><body><script>/* user code */</script></body></html>'
src      = 'javascript: document.write("' + template + '")'
widget   = $('<iframe>').attr('src', src)

$('#container').append(widget)
```

...and then have the resulting iframe be treated as cross-domain from the parent window. Is this possible, and if so, how would it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I think I get what you need but it's a bit tricky.
You want to create an `<iframe>` and populate it with the user Javascript client-side but still have the client sandboxed?

This is fairly non-standard. Usually the contents of the `<iframe>` are generated server side. But here it goes.

First some background: documents can not access the content of any document that is not from the same domain (including sub-domain) and port. But they can change their own security domain using the `document.domain` property. So what you need to do is lighten up the security then tighten it back up again for the user script to run.

So you can't do it the way you specified because if you create an `<iframe>` with a Javascript `src` the `document.domain` will match the parent frame. This means that the widget will have full access to everything.

So here's how you can do it:

1. Set up two sub-domains of your main domain. Let's call them `home.example.com` and `widgets.example.com`.
2. Create a basic HTML file on `widgets.example.com` and make sure it calls this javascript: `document.domain = "example.com";`
3. Now create your page that will contain all these widgets. Set it's `document.domain` to the same value.
4. Create all your iframes loading your basic HTML page from `widgets.example.com` into it.
5. Set a variable inside the frame that contains the user template. Ex: `myFrame.contentWindow.foo = "template";`
6. Switch the `document.domain` on the main window back to `home.example.com` so that the `<iframe>`s will no longer have access to the parent frame
7. Trigger the template substitution in the frame

That last part is the tricky part. You can't just embed the code because if it runs automatically it will run before you can change the domain of the home document back, which will be a security issue. So instead you need to set it to a temporary variable inside the frame then somehow trigger the frame to replace its own contents with that template but only after everything is locked down. The easiest and most compatible way would be to trigger it on resize and then just change the width or height of the frame.

Now, alternatively, if the widget was populated server-side:

1. Host widget on `widgets.example.com`
2. Host page containing widget on `home.example.com`
3. Done

But I assume that you have reasons for doing it all client-side.

The logical next topics: communicating between the frames and auto-sizing. But those are for another day.

Did I answer your question? I hope so because this was a lot of typing and I won't mind the reputation points if you vote up and accept my answer! ;)

Comment: You really shouldn't ask people to upvote/accept. It is the base of this site, asking for it will make a lot of people to the exact opposite! Nevertheless, +1 for the great answer :).

Comment: @gnur Sorry, thanks for the +1. I noticed that @jpadvo's last question was in October and he never commented on or up-voted any of the answers so it was just a friendly poke.

Comment: I only have 11 reputation now, so I'm not able to give upvotes yet. When I can, I will certainly give you one. I'll test it, and if it works I'll accept it, too. :)

Comment: @jpadvo I was just giving you a little bit of a hard time ;). Let me know how it goes and feel free to ask some questions if something seems off. This is a complex topic and these results show up in searches so I want to make sure future readers get some use out of it. Too bad we can't really on HTML5 yet or this would be much easier :).

Comment: @andrew-curioso Haha, right on. I'm currently exploring something interesting with base64 encoding and data uris. In any case, I'll post whatever ends up working.

Comment: @jpadvo that is interesting. I supposed that if you pass the entire script as part of the URL and the URL is on a different domain then it will work... is that what you were thinking? Anyway, good luck.

Comment: I think this is the best solution. Bizarre and arbitrary treatment of iframes and security policies among different browsers makes it really hard to do it purely on the client side. I tried using data uris as the source, which worked in Chrome but not other browsers.

Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I finally got enough reputation to upvote your answer. :)

Comment: You may want to take a look at Conductor.js https://github.com/tildeio/conductor.js